# Iterate through string in memory in Assembly

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm having some troubles accessing each character of a string in turn in Assembly. I have the following code that calls the `print_string` routine, before declaring `'Hello World!', 0` into the `bx` registry:

```
mov bx, HELLO_MSG
call print_string

HELLO_MSG:
  db 'Hello, World!', 0
```

Within `print_string`, I'm able to print the first character of the string by doing this:

```
mov al, [bx]

; Trigger a single character print
mov ah, 0x0e
int 0x10
```

In my basic understanding of assembly, the address of the first character (`H`) got saved into `bx`, so by doing `mov al, [bx]` I'm dereferencing the pointer and assigning the real value of `H` into `al`.

Based on that understanding (please correct me if I'm wrong) I've tried the following approaches:

```
mov cl, bx ; Move the pointer to `cl`
add cl, 1 ; Do pointer arithmetic to add one byte to the address (hopefully referencing the next character)
mov al, [cl] ; Dereference the address
```

But I got this error pointing to the `mov al, [cl]` line:

```
error: invalid effective address
```

I've also tried the following:

```
mov al, [bx] ; Move the dereferenced address to `al` (so `al` has `H`)
add al, 1 ; Increment `al`, but of course I'm getting the ASCII value of `H` + 1, which is not the next character in the string.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Many, many years ago, someone put it this way:
Do you want the box, or what is in the [box]?

> I've also tried the following:

```
mov al, [bx] ; Move the dereferenced address to `al` (so `al` has `H`) 
add al, 1 ; Increment `al`, but of course I'm getting the ASCII value of `H` + 1
```

The CPU is doing exactly what you told it to do!

```
mov al, [bx]
```

Moves the value pointed to by bx into `al` (in your case, H)

```
add al, 1
```

adds 1 to H.

```
add bx, 1
mov al, [bx]
```

Now, al will contain E

Or you could do:

```
mov al, [bx + 1]
```

to get E

In your other code, `bx` is a word sized register (16 bits) and `cl` is a byte sized register (8 bits) you truncated the address hence the invalid address (what do you expect to happed when you try to put 16 bits into an 8 bit register?)

Here is an example:

```
 HELLO_MSG db 'Hello, World!', 0
 HELLO_LEN equ  $ - HELLO_MSG
...
...
...
    mov     si, HELLO_MSG
    xor     bx, bx
Next:
    mov     al, byte [si + bx]
    mov     ah, 0x0e
    int     0x10

    mov     al, 10
    mov     ah, 0x0e
    int     0x10

    inc     bx
    cmp     bx, HELLO_LEN
    jne     Next
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive explanation! It was clear to me how to solve the problem after this.